# forbidden characters in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am receiving a syntax error when trying to insert data into table. This is my insert statement:

```
insert into accounts_data values (myemail@mail.com,123testpass,217624.402235,6009912,Europe/Asia,Digory_Doodles_PS.ttf*Junicode-Bold.ttf);
```

Not sure what is the problem. I am guessing there are some characters forbidden in mysql tables, but which one?

Also tried escaping the underscore char:

```
insert into accounts_data values (myemail@mail.com,123testpass,217624.402235,6009912,Europe/Asia,Digory\_Doodles\_PS.ttf*Junicode-Bold.ttf);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing quotes

```
insert into accounts_data values (myemail@mail.com,123testpass,21764.40235,6009912,Europe/Asia,Digory_Doodles_PS.ttf*Junicode-Bold.ttf);
```

Should be

```
insert into accounts_data values ('myemail@mail.com','123testpass',21764.40235,6009912,'Europe/Asia,Digory_Doodles_PS.ttf*Junicode-Bold.ttf');
```

You may also share exact error and table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE accounts_data`) to provide you with more precise answer.

Comment: @sanjihan : if you find my answer helpfull, you should consider accepting it

Comment: I cant. I need to wait 10min more. Will surely be accepted after that time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to enclose your strings in quotes.